# Condense Horizontal the space between bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In order to save space, I would like to condense the bibliography, specifically, reduce the amount of horizontal space between entries. As an example, see the following figure: too much space among the entry and the description.

[image]

The interesting part of the code is:

```
\scriptsize
\bibliographystyle{something}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Any suggestion on what I can do?

Comment: How can I share it? it is 1565 lines long

Comment: if it is a standard style just tell us the name, otherwise post the whole thing unless it is over the site limit. Most bibliography styles use the width of the widest entry, do you not have another large key elsewhere in the list?

Comment: oh, thank you guys! The key was the size of the largest word as suggested by @DavidCarlisle. Please, answer the question: the solution solves the problem independently from the biblio style. However, the file was created by another colleague of mine. Its size prevents the possibility of sharing it on this page (>1500 line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most bibliography styles using that kind of layout use use the width of the widest entry, so presumably you have a wide entry somewhere else in the list.

You could adjust the key for that entry to abbreviate it more, or use a different style that does not force the same width for all item labels.